# Subthemes in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

How we can display a subtheme in a specific page in drupal, such as a taxonomy page?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to use a subtheme  of your main theme for certain pages?

Have a look at the Sections module, which lets you specify a theme for pages or groups of pages matching a pattern on their URL.

It doesn't matter whether the theme you want to apply is a theme or a subtheme.

Hope this helps,

James

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey). Themekey lets you choose the theme based on a whole lot of different factors, one option is the path

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your hook_boot():

```
function mymodule_boot() {
  if (/* test based on the $_GET['q'] or REQUEST_URI */) {
    $GLOBALS['custom_theme'] = 'myothertheme';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a job for [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) and [spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces). These modules will allow you to set up different themes for different sections of the site based on a set of parameters. It's very flexible and provides a framework to deal with a variety of such theming issues, not just this particular one.

Alternatively you could set up alternative .tpl.php files that are chosen in a preprocess based on the path.